# How to append more data in a column without overriding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I want to add some data in a column such that I have a List I want to pick the data from it some time the List size is more and some time it less than M(where M is number of rows). if it is more than M it should iterate and append the data and separate the data with comma[,] but does not override it if less it should skip the rest of the data or add empty data. also I'm creating column run time

```
def read_tor_cell(self):
    queue = ['a','b','c','a','b','c']
        complete_path = self.Task2 + filename
        print(complete_path)
        for i in queue():
            df_round_robin = self.path_to_csv.head(M)
            df_round_robin["new_column"] = i
            df_round_robin.to_csv('test.csv')
            print(df_round_robin)
```

above script override the previous data.
I Want output like this so that the data does not override

```
expected output:: 

Assume m=2
for row 1:: inside new_column a,c,b
for row 2:: inside new_column b,a,c

m=3
for row 1:: inside new_column a,a
for row 2:: inside new_column b,b
for row 3:: inside new_column c,c
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @gtomer Kindly check it again. I add the expected output

Comment: Please explain again the logic. I do not understand why this is the output

Comment: This is not the output I want output like this. the script I wrote it override data